# Model fits on a single GPU but script crashes when trying to fit on multiple GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that can train fine on a single GPU, but when I try to fit it using multi_gpu_model, I get this CUDA error before the script exits:

```
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:521] Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(handle_.get(), elem_type, nd, dims.data(), strides.data()) == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0)batch_descriptor: {count: 0 feature_map_count: 16 spatial: 128 128 128  value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX}
```

I tried to pass both the compiled and not-compiled version of the model instance to the multi_gpu_model function, but it did not change anything. I call it like this:

```
multi_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
```

The compilation is done this way and does not raise any errors:

```
multi_model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(5e-4),
    loss=dice_coefficient_loss,
    metrics=[dice_coefficient]
            + get_label_wise_dice_coefficient_functions(n_labels))

def dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1.):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return ((2. * intersection + smooth)
            / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth))


def dice_coefficient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred)


def label_wise_dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred, label_index):
    return dice_coefficient(y_true[:, label_index], y_pred[:, label_index])


def get_label_dice_coefficient_function(label_index):
    f = functools.partial(label_wise_dice_coefficient, label_index=label_index)
    f.__setattr__('__name__', 'label_{0}_dice_coef'.format(label_index))
    return f


def get_label_wise_dice_coefficient_functions(n_labels):
    return [get_label_dice_coefficient_function(i) for i in range(n_labels)]
```

(most of these functions and the model architecture have been stolen [here](https://github.com/ellisdg/3DUnetCNN/blob/master/unet3d/metrics.py))

I am using python 3.6.6, tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0, cudatoolkit 9.2, cudnn 7.2.1 from conda main repo and keras-contrib 2.0.8 installed with pip/git on top of a 64-bits CentOS 7.4.1708

Looking at the previous log lines, it looks like the multiple GPUs are properly detected:

```
2018-10-09 16:30:19.977993: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:20:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.74GiB
2018-10-09 16:30:20.318137: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:21:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.74GiB
2018-10-09 16:30:20.595428: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 2 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:22:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.74GiB
2018-10-09 16:30:20.953619: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 3 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:23:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.74GiB
2018-10-09 16:30:20.967429: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2018-10-09 16:30:22.415906: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-10-09 16:30:22.415957: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 1 2 3
2018-10-09 16:30:22.415965: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N Y Y Y
2018-10-09 16:30:22.415971: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 1:   Y N Y Y
2018-10-09 16:30:22.415982: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 2:   Y Y N Y
2018-10-09 16:30:22.415988: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 3:   Y Y Y N
2018-10-09 16:30:22.416681: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10393 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:20:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-09 16:30:22.536003: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10393 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:21:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-09 16:30:22.637811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 10393 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:22:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-09 16:30:22.747698: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 10393 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:23:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-09 16:30:25,557.557:__main__:INFO:Compiling model
2018-10-09 16:30:25,634.634:__main__:INFO:Fitting model
2018-10-09 16:31:31.773355: F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:521] Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(handle_.get(), elem_type, nd, dims.data(), strides.data()) == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0)batch_descriptor: {count: 0 feature_map_count: 16 spatial: 128 128 128  value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX}
/bin/bash: line 1: 160691 Aborted
```

Any help on what I did wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the compilation params?

Comment: @alec_djinn here you go.

Comment: Have you defined the model under CPU scope?

Comment: @kvish what do you mean?

Comment: @nicoco from the keras [multi_gpu](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model) documentation, you can create the base model with cpu scope, then call the multi_gpu utility to train. Since you have custom loss and metrics, I was wondering whether you have placed your base model on cpu or gpu.

Comment: @kvish I guess it is first defined on the GPU scope, since the node I'm running it on is GPU-capable. Following my investigations, I tried to pass `cpu_relocation=True` to `multi_gpu_model`, but it did crash similarly. The message was printed out twice to stderr this time though…

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. I checked the github link you had shared and noticed there are a bunch of callbacks added to the training process. There have been issues training multi gpu models with [callbacks](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8649). Are you using callbacks?

Comment: @kvish I am using callbacks indeed. I just tried to launch the fitting process without callbacks, but I get the same error message again. I guess the metrics are to blame? Or maybe the `InstanceNormalization` layer from `keras_contrib`?

Comment: @nicoco maybe! looking in to the [cudnn file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc#L541), it looks like there is a check fail when converting a batch descriptor structure to a cudnn tensor. So maybe from the given 128 128 128 spatial info and the feature count, you could try to figure out which layer this tensor coming from which might help you narrow down the issue?

Comment: @kvish How could I find this out? There are several 128 128 128 layers in this architecture…

Comment: @nicoco if you have InstanceNormalization layers before you get to this layer and its able to deal with them fine, then you might have some confidence maybe that is not the issue. If this is not the case, then you can take out the normalization and then run the training for example. We can eliminate some possibilities this way.

Comment: and also the count is 0 and feature_map_count is 16. From the [dnn file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/stream_executor/dnn.h#L212), feature_map_count corresponds to RGB info and the count corresponds to minibatch size. So the minibatch size is actually 0 here which seems rather strange

Comment: @kvish It seems strange indeed… I just managed to update to tensorflow 1.11.0 hoping it would help but it didn't. I am a beginner in NN so I am not sure what layer to incriminate. If you feel like taking a look, [here](https://pastebin.com/qAsZ520i) is the model yaml file.

Comment: @kvish Also it doesn't seem related to the install itself since I managed to run a dummy training on 2 GPUs using one of the basic example from the keras documentation, with random inputs.

Comment: @nicoco I am also short on ideas. Have you tried taking out the normalization layers and running the model? That seems to be a good place to start investigation.

Comment: @kvish I finally found time do replace InstanceNormalization with BatchNormalization, eliminating all need for `keras_contrib`. But it didn't change anything. I should probably file a bug report at keras, but first I need to find time to reproduce the bug with a minimal NN architecture because the one I'm using right now is quite deep…

Comment: @nicoco thats great! I hope a bug report in keras can help in figuring out how to approach debugging this problem at the very least! You can also try tensorflow bug report!

Comment: @kvish I figured it out while trying to do a proper bug report. `keras_contrib` was not to blame after all…

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was caused because of a negative dimension error, I had to fix and check the model architecture in a separate file and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the `.fit()` method of a `multi_model_gpu` did not like it when the number of samples in the dataset was not a multiple of the `batch_size`, i.e., the number of GPUs in my case. Ditching a sample from my dataset solved my issue. I reported this bug [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11434).

Comment: Interesting! I did a quick google search about this and there is an article which suggests the [same thing](http://blog.datumbox.com/5-tips-for-multi-gpu-training-with-keras/). But yeah if one GPU is not getting any data batch, then it would be nice if we got an error saying something like that!